# Separating a nested field into two new fields, maintaining order

Tags: sed, awk, cut

I've been trying to break a sample file as below such that the third column becomes two parts while maintaining order within the file.

> 100 400 500.00APPLE 5.8 9.2
>
> 200 300 600.00DOG 5.3 9.1
>
> 300 763 454.44KITTEN 5.7 9.2

Should result in

> 100 400 500.00 APPLE 5.8 9.2
>
> 200 300 600.00 DOG 5.3 9.1
>
> 300 763 454.44 KITTEN 5.7 9.2

I've toyed doing this in awk but seem to be having issues.

PS: The point upon which to separate is always a digit [0-9] followed by [a-zA-Z] in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/' ./infile
100 400 500.00 APPLE 5.8 9.2
200 300 600.00 DOG 5.3 9.1
300 763 454.44 KITTEN 5.7 9.2
```

---

Or if you have `gawk` you can limit the split to just the 3rd field by using:

```
awk '{$3=gensub(/([0-9])([A-Z])/,"\\1 \\2","",$3)}1' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk '{$3=gensub(/([0-9])([A-Z])/,"\\1 \\2","",$3)}1' ./infile
100 400 500.00 APPLE 5.8 9.2
200 300 600.00 DOG 5.3 9.1
300 763 454.44 KITTEN 5.7 9.2
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. I kind of figured it could be done in sed... it took me some glances and reading of http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html to see how your solution works but understand it now.

Comment: @jp: no problem. Note that the `sed` script will split the *first occurrence* of a number followed by a letter. If you have lines where this pattern occurs in the 1st or 2nd field, it **will** split that.  If you want to be sure the split only happens on the 3rd field then the `awk` script is the way to go.

Comment: For understanding sake, say I wanted to extend this to one step further, putting # signs in place of the spaces, but ONLY between digits.  ie.  100 400 500.00 APPLE 5.8 9.2 becomes 100#400#500.00 APPLE 5.8#9.2.  I'm trying to understand the \1 and \2 better but obviously it only matches first,second occurrence. It would be nice if sed supported more sophisticated temp variable-like holders (but maybe it does?). Thanks again.

Comment: Ahh got it s/\([0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1#\2/g

Comment: Or all in one pass: `sed -e 's/ /#/g' -e 's/\([0-9]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/' file`